How do I get data to display in a DT when using runtime: shiny in the YAML header of my flexdashboard document?
I have a flexdashboard document. In one section I wish to display a DT data table.
I hope to use the DT in a reactive context where clicking on a row returns the value of one of the columns for use in another shiny component.
The problem I have is that no rows of data appear in the DT. Below is a screen shot demonstrating the problem. As you can see on the right, there is data to be displayed.
Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?
If my YAML header looks like this:
---
title: "Emerald Gardens"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    css: "../05_css/eg.css"
    runtime: shiny
---

I get that output.

On the other hand, if I change my YAML header to look like this:
---
title: "Emerald Gardens"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    css: "../05_css/eg.css"
---

I get the expected output:

The two code chunks are these:
    # Data
    eg_plotting_tbl <- read_rds("../02_processed_data/eg_plotting_tbl.rds")

    data <- eg_plotting_tbl %>% 
        select(c(situs_address, 
                 lot_sq_ft, 
                 bulding_area, 
                 bedrooms, 
                 baths, 
                 pool, 
                 waterfront, 
                 eff_yr_built, 
                 account))
    
    data <- data %>% 
        mutate(lot_sq_ft = format(lot_sq_ft, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) %>% 
        mutate(bulding_area = format(bulding_area, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) %>% 
        mutate(bedrooms = as.factor(bedrooms)) %>% 
        mutate(baths = as.factor(baths))
   

and
        datatable(data,
                  elementId = "property_characteristics_table",
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  colnames = c("Address",
                               "Lot Size (sq.ft.)",
                               "Building Size (sq.ft.)",
                               "Bedrooms",
                               "Baths",
                               "Pool",
                               "Waterfront",
                               "Effective Year Built",
                               "account"),
                  filter = "top",
                  options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = "105px", targets = 0),
                                                   list(width = "30px", targets = c(3,6)),
                                                   list(className = "dt-right", targets = c(1,2,3,4)),
                                                   list(className = "dt-center",
                                                        width = "30px",
                                                        targets = c(5,6,7)),
                                                   list(visible = FALSE, targets = 8))
                  )
                )


Here's an R script containing a shiny app. It displays the table as described earlier and exhibits the interactivity I wanted. What I'm looking for is a way to incorporate this, with whatever necessary changes, into a tab on a flexdashboard page:
library(DT)
library(shiny)

eg_plotting_tbl <- read_rds("../02_processed_data/eg_plotting_tbl.rds")

data_table <- eg_plotting_tbl %>% 
    select(c(situs_address, 
             lot_sq_ft, 
             bulding_area, 
             bedrooms, 
             baths, 
             pool, 
             waterfront, 
             eff_yr_built, 
             account))

data_table <- data_table %>% 
    mutate(lot_sq_ft = format(lot_sq_ft, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) %>% 
    mutate(bulding_area = format(bulding_area, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) %>% 
    mutate(bedrooms = as.factor(bedrooms)) %>% 
    mutate(baths = as.factor(baths))


ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(8, DTOutput("myTable")),
        column(
            4,
            h4("Account for selected row"), 
            verbatimTextOutput("selected")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$myTable <- renderDT({
        datatable(data_table,
                  selection = "single",
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  colnames = c("Address", 
                               "Lot Size (sq.ft.)", 
                               "Building Size (sq.ft.)", 
                               "Bedrooms", 
                               "Baths", 
                               "Pool", 
                               "Waterfront", 
                               "Effective Year Built",
                               "account"),
                  filter = "top",
                  options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = "115px", targets = 0),
                                                   list(width = "30px", targets = c(3,6)),
                                                   list(className = "dt-right", targets = c(1,2,3,4)),
                                                   list(className = "dt-center", 
                                                        width = "30px", 
                                                        targets = c(5,6,7)),
                                                   list(visible = FALSE, targets = 8))
                  ))
    })
    
    output$selected <- renderPrint({
        selected_row <- input$myTable_rows_selected
        if (length(selected_row) > 0) {
            selected_value <- data_table[selected_row, 9, drop = TRUE]
            print(selected_value)
        } else {
            "No row selected"
        }
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I see no Shiny in your code chunks.  But your example is not reproducible (you haven't supplied your Quarto(?) document nor given us access to your data.  So it's impossible to know exactly what is going on.

I am working my way up to the shiny reactive point. Rather than attempt to create the entire app all at once, my plan was first to display the DT without creating it as an object that can respond to user action. Only after I got the display working I planned to add the reactive parts. So yes, you are correct, it isn't reproducible, but I believe that it has everything needed for a person experienced in creating flexdashboard / shiny documents to point out my error(s). If there is someone who can point out what's missing, I'll thank you.

I believe this is the same issue I faced here. Try getting rid of the indent before runtime: shiny in your YAML

Thanks for your reply. I found the same advice about a half-hour ago in a thread on a private Slack channel. I've been struggling for days with this. ChatGPT has been no help on this, but does help on many other issues.
